# Correct premature merge to the upstream branch

Tags: git

After I merged my feature branch to `development` branch. I started new branch and make some commits already.

```
<D1><-------------------<D2>                   development
  \                     /  \
   <f11><--<f12><--<f13>    \                  add-stuff-f1
                             \
                              <f21><--<f22>    add-stuff-f2
```

I realized the `f21` and `f22` should be in the `add-stuff-f1` ebacause they are really related. I would like to have something like this:

```
<D1><-----------------------------------<D2>   development
  \                                     /
   <f11><--<f12><--<f13><--<f21><--<f22>       add-stuff-f1
```

Can I make some simple actions with Git to do that?

Comment: Not familiar with your workflow, but would simply rebasing <f21> onto <f13>, then merging <f22> back into a <D3> be sufficient?

Comment: Is it that the same as 'checkout development' and 'merge --no-ff add-stuff-f2' ?

Comment: @flyer may I suggest a different title for this question, something like: "Correct premature merge to the upstream branch"? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
git rebase --onto add-stuff-f1 development add-stuff-f2
```

If there are conflicts during merge resolve them manually and then run

```
git rebase --continue
```

Then

```
git checkout add-stuff-f1
```

and reset it to the new add-stuff-f2 head:

```
git reset --hard add-stuff-f2
```

Now you can delete add-stuff-f2 if you want to.

```
git branch -d add-stuff-f2
```

Next

```
git checkout development
```

and get rid of your previous merge to it

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Finally merge into development again as you did before

```
git merge --no-ff add-stuff-f1
```

You're done, good luck.

Comment: I learned something knew. Question though: Did you have to use --no-ff for the last merge?

Comment: @JohnnyZ: techinally you're correct, but if there are no commits between D1 and D2 (I assumed there might be) then why not let Git do a fast-forward, what harm will it do?

Comment: The target was for me to keep topic branch (eventually delete this branch). Just --no-ff at last merge could make exact state I put in the Q.

Comment: You're right, I just added `--no-ff` to the answer above

Answer (score 1):

Attaching add-stuff-f2 to add-stuff-f1 WITHOUT bringing in all the stuff from the development branch between D1 and D2, is a challenge. To solve that I would cherry-pick the commits from add-stuff-f2 into add-stuff-f1.

If there are no changes between D1 and D2, then this problem is really simple actually:

add-stuff-f1 and development should be pointing to the same commit.
add-stuff-f2 is linearly ahead of both of these by two commits.

To solve do two fast-forward merges:

```
switch to the add-stuff-f1 branch. Do "git merge add-stuff-f2". 
switch to the development branch. Do "git merge add-stuff-f2"
```

The result will move the development and add-stuff-f1 pointers to the same commit as add-stuff-f2. Then you can delete f2(if you no longer need it), and do more commits on f1 to continue with development of feature one.

Comment: There is no changes between. My printings show exact commits. Your solution seems to be the same as just `checkout development` and `merge --no-ff add-stuff-f2`.